# How do I connect two pieces of flexible dryer hose

Tags: dryer

I need about 10 to 12 feet of flexible dryer hose but it seems to come in 8 foot lengths .
Is it possible to connect a 4 foot section to an 8 foot length.
And how would I proceed.

Comment: Do yourself a HUGE favor and use solid metal dryer duct, not the flexible hose.

Answer (score 3):

Do consider replacing any accessible hose with smooth-wall (rigid or semi-rigid) ducting, but in a pinch you can just use a short section of rigid duct and a pair of hose clamps.

Comment: The reason it only comes in 8 ft. lengths is that is the maximum allowed by code. Not sure what "in a pinch" means, but an additional 4 ft. if flex is not allowed.